# Difference between varchar(5) and varchar(5000)?

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there an advantage to varchar(500) over varchar(8000)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009694/is-there-an-advantage-to-varchar500-over-varchar8000)

In SQL Server we can specify the field type `varchar(n)`:

> Storage size is the actual length in bytes of the data entered, not n
>   bytes.

Often when planning a database structure I try to imagine the maximum possible length of strings which are to be stored in these `varchar` fields and then set that imagined size + some backup for the `varchar` field. Sometimes it may occur that the initially provided room is not enough for the field and then I need to increase the length.

But actually, is it worth limiting the `varchar` field to some value and not just set something like `varchar(5000)` or even `varchar(max)` which will 100% suit the case? Is there any advantage maybe in page organization in SQL Server or index organization when I limit that `n` length?

**Update**

Here is what I mean (the advantage): https://stackoverflow.com/a/5353196/355264

> Yes, the query optimizer can guess how many rows fit in a page, if you
>   have a lot of varchar fields that are larger than necessary, SQL
>   Server can internally guess the wrong number of rows.

Is the above true? And are there any other advantages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there an advantage to varchar(500) over varchar(8000)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009694/is-there-an-advantage-to-varchar500-over-varchar8000) or of [varchar(max) everywhere?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091284/varcharmax-everywhere) or of [SQL Server VARCHAR Column Width](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11614/sql-server-varchar-column-width)

Comment: RE: Your edit. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009694/is-there-an-advantage-to-varchar500-over-varchar8000/5654947#5654947)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For one thing - you **CANNOT** index any column that's over 900 bytes in size.

That alone (to me) is a killer criteria against using `varchar(5000)` (or `varchar(max)`) all the time, even if not needed....

Use the appropriate size.

Also: `varchar` adds at least 2 bytes of overhead, so for strings of 10 characters or less, I would always recommend using `char(n)` instead.

`char(5)` will use 5 bytes of storage - always. `varchar(5)` uses between 2 and 7 bytes of storage.

Comment: So actually `varchar(15)` will be the same as `varchar(500)` in the terms of efficiency and speed, right? I.e. if I think the data will be around 15-20 bytes (maybe less or longer a bit) I can just specify `varchar(150)`? This is actually my main question.

Comment: I don't understand that "always"... the question being between using varchar(500) or varchar(max) rules out any suggestion that the strings are usually going to be 10 characters or less.

Comment: A column of type `char(100)` will **always** be exactly 100 characters long - even if you store only `Isaac` in it, it will be padded to the defined length (of 100 characters) with spaces - so really you're storing `Isaac....................` - which is highly inefficient

Comment: The padding for a column depends on if you have set ANSI_PADDING ON/OFF.

Answer (score 15):

MS SQL Server stores varchar(8000) and shorter differently from varchar(MAX).

> The size at which MAX types are moved out of a table's data pages and
>   into its own data pages is now fixed at 8,000 bytes if [large value
>   types out of row] is set to OFF.
>
> - http://www.fotia.co.uk/fotia/DY.13.VarCharMax.aspx

There are several reasons why you would use use varchar(n) rather than varchar(MAX)

**Performance**

varchar(n) is faster
http://rusanu.com/2010/03/22/performance-comparison-of-varcharmax-vs-varcharn/

**Indexing**

varchar(900) and smaller can be indexed, but not varchar(MAX) or varchar(901) or larger

**Compatibility**

MS SQL Server Compact Edition does not support varchar(MAX)